# Correctly Using checked function of Wordpress

Tags: php, widgets

In the Public Function `Update` this code is sitting →

> ```
> `public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
>
>       $instance['description_box'] = $new_instance['description_box'];
> ```

In the public function widget, this code is sitting →

> ```
> public function widget($args, $instance) {
>
>     $description_box = $instance[ 'description_box' ] ? 'true' : 'false';
> ```

In the public function→

> ```
> public function form( $instance ) {
> ```

This code is sitting →

> ```
> <p> <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance[ 'description_box' ], 'on' ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'description_box' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'description_box' ); ?>" />
>         <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'description_box' ); ?>">Check whether to display description or not</label>
>         </p>
> ```

Now what i want is when the condition is true i.e. the box is checked then execute some code.

```
If ($description_box is true) {
<p>some text</p>

}
```

How to correctly write this using this →https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked

Update →

I tried using this →

```
<?php if($description_box==0){ ?>
                                    <p><</p>
                                    <?php } ?>
```

But the problem is if the widget is in 2 different sidebars, in one checkbox ticked and in another not, but the result is same in both i.e. it either displays `<p></p>` or not based on the either `$description_box` is set to 0/1 or true/false in the `php` `if condition`. whats the remedy?

Comment: What's the actual problem here? "it either displays <p></p> or not based on the either $description_box is set to 0/1 or true/false in the php if condition" sounds like it's doing what you want.

Comment: Widgets go to different sidebars? I have two sidebars and when I drag the widget in these two sidebars: In one widget, which is placed in sidebar1 I ticked the check box, and in another widget(same widget), which is placed in the sidebar 2 I didn't check the check box, but both the widget(same widgets) in 2 different sidebars have the same behaviour either they are displaying the `<p></p>` or not at the same time, but the truth is that in one widget-sidebar arrangement we have opted to check the check box, and in another we didn't. Did you get my Point now?

Comment: Where are you setting the `$description_check_box` variable, before you compare it? This is the behaviour you'd see if that variable wasn't set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, based on your full code, there's 3 problems:

Line 60 of your code is missing a semi colon and throwing a fatal error. So:

```
$instance['description_check_box'] = $new_instance['description_check_box']
```

Should be:

```
$instance['description_check_box'] = $new_instance['description_check_box'];
```

On line 66, you're using strings instead of proper boolean `true` or `false` values. Both if these are 'truthy' (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693908/2684861) to another question for what that means), so will both resolve as `true` if used in an if statement. `if ('false')` is `true`. So:

```
$description_check_box = $instance[ 'description_check_box' ] ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Should be:

```
$description_check_box = $instance[ 'description_check_box' ] ? true : false;
```

On line 121 you haven't got `on` in quotes, so you're comparing `$description_check_box` to the *constant* `on`. This should be in quotes if you want to check if the value of `$description_check_box` is `on`. So:

```
<?php if($description_check_box==on){ ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php if($description_check_box=='on'){ ?>
```

BUT. This still won't work. Because you'd be setting `$description_check_box` to `true` or `false` based on whether it's checked on line 66, but later you're checking if the value is `'on'`.

You either need to set the value of `$description_check_box` to `'on'`, or change your comparison to checking if `$description_check_box` is `true`.

You should also use `isset()` before using `$instance['description_check_box']`, because otherwise you'll get an undefined index notice in the customiser when WP_Debug is enabled.

Refer to my other answer for my approach, which avoids all these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full implementation of a simple widget with a checkbox that hides/shows something on the front end:

```
class Checkbox_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'checkbox-widget',
            'Checkbox widget',
            array(
                'classname' => 'widget_checkbox',
            )
        );
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        $checkbox = isset( $instance['checkbox'] ) ? $instance['checkbox'] : false;

        $args['before_widget'];

        if ( $checkbox === 'on' ) {
            echo 'I\'m checked!';
        }

        $args['after_widget'];
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $checkbox = isset( $instance['checkbox'] ) ? $instance['checkbox'] : false;
        ?>

        <p><input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'checkbox' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'checkbox' ); ?>" <?php checked( $checkbox, 'on' ); ?>>

        <?php
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $new_instance['checkbox'] = $new_instance['checkbox'] === 'on' ? 'on' : false;

        return $new_instance;
    }
}
```

Based on you answers to my comment, I think we're you're going wrong is not getting the current value of the checkbox correctly. See, in my example, how the value of `$instance['checkbox']` is being set to `on` if it's checked, and then in the widget I'm checking if it equals `on` when outputting.

Comment: Take another look now, after seeing this comment, I copied the incomplete version of the code into my answer and it was full of mistakes. Should be ok now.

Comment: why some one downvoted you?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Could be because they saw the original answer that was horribly wrong, or because I didn't really answer your question and just posted example code. If you post your full code, then I might be able to actually see what your problem is and explain it.

Comment: Your solution is not working.

Comment: Yes it does. That exact class works and creates a widget that works correctly. The issue exists within your code, but unless you post all the code for your widget, no one can properly help.

Comment: Posted the whole widget code.

Comment: Please do not copy paste the whole code as I will delete the whole code.Juts provide the fix for incorrect part of code.